# Make whitespace bigger with CSS

Tags: css, whitespace

I have a font where the whitespaces are pretty small. I would like to make them bigger via CSS (instead of using multiple spaces for more room).

Is it possible to make whitespace bigger via CSS? Any other solutions if not?

Comment: Is your question answered? If yes, please pick an answer. If no, please comment on the answers given to clarify what is missing.

Comment: @connexo seems like your in a hurry ;) …

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`word-spacing`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_word-spacing.asp) is probably what you're looking for.

Example from [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_text_word-spacing):

```css
.a {
  word-spacing: normal;
}

.b {
  word-spacing: 30px;
}

.c {
  word-spacing: 1cm;
}
```

```html
<h1>The word-spacing Property</h1>

<h2>word-spacing: normal:</h2>
<p class="a">This is some text. This is some text.</p>

<h2>word-spacing: 30px:</h2>
<p class="b">This is some text. This is some text.</p>

<h2>word-spacing: 1cm:</h2>
<p class="c">This is some text. This is some text.</p>
```

Comment: Didn't even know that this property exists.

Answer (score 2):

You have two CSS properties that affect white-space:

- `letter-spacing` controls the white-space between each character;
- `word-spacing` controls the white-space between words.

```css
.word-spacing-10 {word-spacing: 10px}
.letter-spacing-3 {letter-spacing: 3px}
```

```html
<p class="word-spacing-10">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</p>
<p class="letter-spacing-3">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</p>
```

Note that CSS has no way to affect the display characteristics of specific characters (like the space character e.g.).